# Update a component after useState value updates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-state

Having a monaco-editor inside a React component:

```
<Editor defaultValue={defaultValue} defaultLanguage='python' onChange={onChangeCode} />
```

The `defaultValue`, the default code inside of the editor, is sent via props to the component:

```
const MyComponent = ({
  originalCode
}: MyComponentProps) => {
  const [defaultValue, setDefaultValue] = useState(originalCode);
```

When the user edits the code, `onChange={onChangeCode}` is called:

```
  const onChangeCode = (input: string | undefined) => {
    if (input) {
      setCode(input);
    }
  };
```

My question is, how to reset the code to the original one when the user clicks on `Cancel`?

Initially it was like:

```
  const handleCancel = () => {
    onChangeCode(defaultValue);
  };
```

but it didn't work, probably because useState is asynchronous, any ideas how to fix this?

Here is the whole component for more context:

```
import Editor from '@monaco-editor/react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

import { Button, HeaderWithButtons } from '../shared/ui-components';

import { ICalculationEngine } from '../../../lib/constants/types';
import { usePostScript } from '../../../lib/hooks/use-post-script';
import { scriptPayload } from '../../../mocks/scriptPayload';
import { editorDefaultValue } from '../../../utils/utils';
export interface ScriptDefinitionProps {
  realInputDetails: Array<ICalculationEngine['RealInputDetails']>;
  realOutputDetails: ICalculationEngine['RealInputDetails'];
  originalCode: string;
  scriptLibId: string;
  data: ICalculationEngine['ScriptPayload'];
}

const ScriptDefinition = ({
  realInputDetails,
  realOutputDetails,
  originalCode
}: ScriptDefinitionProps) => {
  const [defaultValue, setDefaultValue] = useState(originalCode);
  const [code, setCode] = useState(defaultValue);
  const { handleSubmit } = useForm({});
  const { mutate: postScript } = usePostScript();
  const handleSubmitClick = handleSubmit(() => {
    postScript(scriptPayload);
  });
  const handleCancel = () => {
    onChangeCode(defaultValue);
  };

  const onChangeCode = (input: string | undefined) => {
    if (input) {
      setCode(input);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setDefaultValue(editorDefaultValue(realInputDetails, realOutputDetails));
  }, [realInputDetails, realOutputDetails, originalCode]);

  return (
    <div>
      <HeaderWithButtons>
        <div>
          <Button title='cancel' onClick={handleCancel} />
          <Button title='save' onClick={handleSubmitClick} />
        </div>
      </HeaderWithButtons>
      <Editor defaultValue={defaultValue} defaultLanguage='python' onChange={onChangeCode} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ScriptDefinition;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the ability to change the value externally, you'll need to use the `Editor` as a controlled component by passing the `value` prop ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/editor-clear-value-4wiqjr?file=/src/App.js)):

**For example:**

```
const defaultValue = "// let's write some broken code ";

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(defaultValue);

  const handleCancel = () => {
    setValue(defaultValue);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button title="cancel" onClick={handleCancel}>
        Cancel
      </button>

      <Editor
        value={value}
        onChange={setValue}
        height="90vh"
        defaultLanguage="javascript"
      />
    </>
  );
}
```